# Countable image and a constant function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

F:R to R has a countable image. Then f is a constant function.

Prove this statement.

I'm not really sure what it means a countable image and then really what to do with that. Any suggestions?

Edit:

So my thought is if the image is countable the only connected subsets are singletons, thus (for some slightly unclear reason) F only sends points to a singleton thus is constant. Right idea?

Comment: This is not true. Do you assume also that $F$ is continuous?

Answer (score 0):

If the function has a countable image then the set of elements which compose the image biject with the natural numbers. But as John Ma said this statement is false, so I would recommend checking to see you wrote the problem down correctly.

Comment: Most likely the assumption is that $F$ is a continuous function that happens to have a "countable image".   Think about the intermediate value theorem at the same time as you are pondering this.

Comment: I did copy it down correctly, but it seems pretty clear that continuity should be assumed